# Redirection after succesfull login Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

After a successful login. What could be the reason I am not redirected to /admin/notifications. I enter at "contextpath/" when I log in. What am I missing?

```
<!-- Spring security -->
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:http pattern="/admin/login" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/resources/public/**" security="none" />
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/admin/login" default-target-url="/admin/notifications" always-use-default-target="true"  authentication-failure-url="/admin/login?error=1" login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="" logout-url="/admin/logout" logout-success-url="/admin/login"/>
</security:http>
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" ></security:http>
```

Edit: The authentication-manager. It lives in another xml file that is included from the main application context.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

This is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/notifications")
public class NotificationControllerAdmin {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNotifications(Model model){
        return "admin/notifications/notifications";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your authenticationManager?

Comment: @mvb13 please se my edit.

Comment: All looks fine. Are you sure that you aren't redirected to "/admin/notifications"(This means that logic inside controller is correct)?

Comment: @mvb13 Here is also my controller. I really can't se what I am doing wrong.

Comment: your controller is being called? if u put a breakpoint in it, the debuggeer stops there?

Comment: @OhadR No it does not run the controller code. My controller works it I hit the url when already login. It is just the configuration that doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have two blocks in your spring configuration <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" > ?

Comment: mvb13 is correct. The second block will override the existing one, meaning none of the configuration from the first one applies. Note that it's a good idea to say what actually happens, rather than what doesn't. If you'd said here "I'm redirected to x instead of y" it would have been easier to guess what was wrong.

Comment: @mvb13 You cant write it as an answer. I will test it soon.

Comment: @LukeTaylor if I remove the bottom one I get http://localhost:8080/ContextPath/j_spring_security_check and a method POST not supported. When I press login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second spring-security configuration block `<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >` probably overrides all settings specified in first one.

Comment: Thats is exactly what I want. A view with that name. The controller works just not together with Spring security configuration.

Comment: Ok.One more question. Can you please put a breakpoint on this line (return "admin/notifications/notifications";), to launch application in debug mode and to prove that after login you don't enter the Controller getNotifications method.

Comment: This solved my first problem bu caused another one. I get localhost:8080/ContextPath/j_spring_security_check and a method POST not supported. When I press login. But you solved initial configuration problem.